# Is this gcc "sequence point" UB warning valid in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buf[100], *p = buf;
    p = buf + sprintf(p=buf, "%d", 123);
    return 0;
}
```

Using gcc 9.3.0 or 12.1.0 with -std=c17 (or c11/c99/c89) I get:
`warning: operation on ‘p’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`
pointing to the `=` in `p = buf +...`.
I see p is being assigned to twice in one expression, but there is a sequence point after the assignment in the the function call. Can this be undefined behavior?

The code was originally `p += sprintf(p=buf, "%d", 123);`. That got the same warning, pointing to `+=`. Is this the same situation? Is this UB?

Comment: I think there's a sequence point before/after the function call, so gcc's warning might be wrong here.  Paging language lawyers!

Comment: Just OOC, why is `p=buf` in the call at all? `p` is already `buf` (from when it was initialized). Passing `buf` directly would have worked just fine (no need to assign `p` at that point anyway). The question remains valid, I'm just wondering why this came up at all.

Comment: Standard C library “functions” may be implemented as function-like macros, in which case the behavior of the statement might not be defined by the C standard. If you write it as `p = buf + (sprintf)(p=buf, "%d", 123);`, then `sprintf` cannot be a function-like macro, and the sequence point before the call sequences the `p` accesses. But why not just use `p = buf + sprintf(buf, "%d", 123);`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: For that matter, why use `p` at all? The example is almost too minimal.

Comment: Wikipedia's [Sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) has *4. Before a function is entered in a function call. The order in which the arguments are evaluated is not specified, but this sequence point means that all of their side effects are complete before the function is entered.*

Comment: @ShadowRanger, @sj95126, Eric: The original was more like `p += sprintf(p=buf, "%d", 123);`, intended to format to buf but leave p pointing to the next available location to receive more formatted data. I redid it as p = `buf +...` to remove any implication that it would be seen as `p = p +...` which would muddy the issue with respect to additional fetches of `p`. It's not my code but I'm just wondering about UB and the gcc warning.

Comment: There is no sequencing guarantee in C either sode of the `=` operator.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: Nobody says there is. But there is a sequence point after evaluation of function arguments and before the call. So `p=buf` as an argument must be fully evaluated before the outer assignment updates `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue we are concerned about is whether `p` is both modified twice without sequencing, per C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined…

As explained below, GCC is wrong to complain there may be undefined behavior due to this, subject to ensuring that `sprintf` is a function call. Per 7.1.4 1, any function declared in a standard library header may additionally be implemented as a function-like macro. This means that `sprintf` may be macro-replaced in `p = buf + sprintf(p=buf, "%d", 123);`, yielding some expression in which there is no sequencing between `p=buf` and larger `p = buf +…`. However, [GCC complains even when this possibility is suppressed by enclosing `sprintf` in parentheses](https://godbolt.org/z/qehad9nhP), using `p = buf + (sprintf)(p=buf, "%d", 123);`.

The two accesses of `p` in question are its updates performed as side effects of the assignments. An assignment evaluates its left operand for its lvalue, evaluates its right operand, and, as a side effect, updates the object referred to by its left operand. The first two evaluations are unsequenced, but evaluating the left operand for its lvalue is neither a side effect on the referenced object nor a value computation using its value, so we are unconcerned with it. (Evaluating `p` for its lvalue is trivial; `p` refers to the object named “p”. Evaluating an expression for its lvalue is more complicated in expressions such as `q[3+f(x)]`, which must evaluate the subscript expression and, if `q` is a pointer rather than an array, retrieve its value. Then a final address is calculated, which serves for the lvalue of the object being assigned to.)

For the assignment, C 2018 6.5.16 3 says:

> … The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands…

This means the update of `p` in the larger assignment is sequenced after the value computations of the operands, but it does not tell us the update is sequenced after the update in `p=buf`.

However, `p=buf` appears in the arguments of `sprintf`. C 2018 6.5.2.2 10 tells us:

> There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call…

Per 5.1.2.3 3, “… The presence of a *sequence* point between the evaluation of expressions *A* and *B* implies that every value computation and side effect associated with *A* is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with *B*…

There is a problem here. We can easily take *A* as `p=buf`, and there is a sequence point between this *A* and, say, the call to `sprintf`, and therefore the side effect associated with *A* is sequenced before the call to `sprintf`. However, what do we use for *B* to ensure that the side effect of the larger assignment `p = buf + …` is after the sequence point? We cannot take *B* to be this larger assignment itself because then the sequence point would not be between *A* and *B*; it would be after *A* but somewhere inside *B*.

My interpretation is this is a defect in the wording of the standard. If we need to literally identify some entirely separate expression *B* in order to apply this rule about sequence points, then the presence of a sequence point before the function call loses much of its effect. It would not make much sense to say there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the arguments and literally the “actual call” since the “actual call” is not an expression. So the wording about sequence points between expressions must be intended to apply to parts of expressions or things done in the course of evaluating expressions.

If `sprintf` were an ordinary routine instead of a library routine, this would not be a problem. In an ordinary routine, there are expressions inside the function, and the sequence point means our *A* (`p=buf`) is sequenced before those expressions, and those expressions are in turn sequenced before the update of `p` for the larger `p = buf + …` because they are part of the right operand of `=`, whose evaluation is sequenced before the side effect of updating `p`. However, C library routines are specified “holistically,” as special routines that perform stated effects, not as ordinary C code. Nonetheless, my interpretation is that the argument `p=buf` is intended to be completed before the function call and as part of the right operand of the larger `p = buf +…` and hence its side effect is sequenced before the side effect in that larger assignment.

Comment: "However, GCC complains even when this possibility is suppressed by enclosing sprintf in parentheses, using p = buf + sprintf(p=buf, "%d", 123);." Is there a typo here? `sprintf` doesn't appear to be "enclosed in parentheses" in the example. I'm not sure whether this should mean `(sprintf)(p=buf, "%d", 123)`, or `(sprintf(p=buf, "%d", 123))`, or something else.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, thanks, fixed, forgot to edit after pasting. It is correct in the link to Godbolt.

Comment: I wonder if your missing expressions aren't those in the body of the called function. The non-cited part of 6.5.2.2/10 seems to hint so, but that's not crystal clear. Now what about an empty function?

Comment: Isn't the `p = ` actually a value computation _of the pointer_ though? If the compiler starts by doing "ok lets save down the address where to assign all of this later", then the `p =` is unsequenced in relation to `p=buf`.

Comment: In more artificial scenarios such as `*func(p=&a) = *func(p=&b);` this becomes more obvious. Where does `p` point at after this expression? This is surely UB.

Comment: @Lundin: No, in `p =`, `p` is only evaluated for its lvalue. Its value is not used. In `*func(p=&a) = *func(p=&b);`, both assignments to `p` could be evaluated before either call to `func`, so there would be no sequence point between them, and the behavior would be undefined. (When there are multiple allowed orderings, and any one of them has undefined behavior, the standard says it does not define the behavior even if the compiler chooses one of the well-defined orderings.)

Comment: I can't find any formal definition for what "value computation" entails, other than (5.1.2.3) "Value computation for an lvalue expression includes determining the identity of the designated object". It's a C11 term and all of this is pretty unclear after C11... C99 was clearer: "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored."

Comment: Eric, thank you for your thoughtful response. You didn't exactly say this is not UB, but apparently agree with me that it's not. So I consider this a bogus gcc warning. Too bad it's so hard to specify semantics exactly in natural language. I'm accepting this answer.